# How to combine 2 regression from two data sets, same coefficient?

Tags: regression, bayesian-network

I have two data sets of gene expression and cause of they're made by two different platforms, I can't merge them. Now I have two regression with same coefficients:

y=B01+B11X1+B12X2

y=B02+B12X1+B22X2

How can I merge them to get one regression model?

attention: these regression models are output of two Bayesian networks reconstructed by continuous variables. There is an article "A novel method for combining Bayesian networks, theoretical analysis, and its applications" . But this article about discrete data. Estimated parameters in Bayesian network by continuous variables is also as estimate regression coefficients. So I want to combine two regression models to combine two Bayesian network.

Answer (score 0):

My wild guess is that you use the merged dataset but introduce a new predictor, type of platform. This my new proposed model: 
$E(Y|X) = \alpha + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + \beta_3 X_3$
where $X_3=1$ if on platform 1.

Comment: I think this isn't good model.

Comment: Could you elaborate?